# Git subtree, submodules - working with a project inside another one

Tags: git, package, git-submodules, git-subtree

I'm trying to figure out how to use git subtree (from what I saw, submodules isn't what I want) in order to work on two git repository at the same time where one project is inside the other one.

In my case, I'm working with Unity with my main repository. I decided I wanted to make some of my code as a package, so I have in the folder repositoryRoot/Packages/com.mypackage another git repository, so I can use the package in my future projects.

I don't understand which commands and git features I'm supposed to use to be able to commit to both repositories separetely, and I guess, commit changes to the package only to the package's repository and not also the main project (or should I ?).

Comment: As far as I understood, you have a project, that includes a component. You would like to use this component in other projects. Is that correct? 
If yes, then there's another question: when this shared component is modified in one of the projects where it's used, should this modification apply to all other projects?

Comment: That's it. I know the code I'm writing right now will be used in future projects. However, the code is not done and I need to be able to modify it from the parent project, and apply my changes to a git repository from which I will pull the code. Because of the way Unity works, I have access to a package manager for git so there is no need of constantly pulling the updated code (I'm not working on multiple parallel projects). From what I've seen and tested, the git subtree allows me to push commits to the parent repository and then update the package repository so that's what I'm going for now.

Comment: As an alternative, I would suggest to use [Git X-Modules](https://gitmodules.com) that provides more flexibility than git subtree.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think it is overkill for my case but might be interesting in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's worth noting that `git subtree` is a kind of [red-headed stepchild](https://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-red2.htm) in the Git world.  It might be unwise to depend too much on it.

That aside, there's a huge difference between subtree and submodule:

- A Git *submodule* is simply a case of taking some existing Git repository and *using it* from some other Git repository.  To do so, the user—which we call the *superproject*—simply lists the path name and URL where Git should run a `git clone` to clone the use-ee, or the *submodule*.  This listing goes into a `.gitmodules` file, maintained by the `git submodule` command.  Once cloned, the superproject will then occasionally `cd` into the submodule and run `git checkout --detach hash`, where the *hash ID* to be used is stored in *each commit you make in the superproject*.  These are called *gitlinks* and the *always* result in a detached HEAD.

  The upshot of this is that when you work in the superproject, you don't do any work *in* the submodule: the superproject simply calls for some commit that *already exists* in that submodule.  If the commit you need doesn't exist, what you have to do is find or create a clone of the submodule repository, work there, create the commit you need, make sure it's all good, push it back to the place that your superproject will clone from so that the commit exists for *everyone*, and only then make a new commit *in* the superproject that refers to this new submodule commit via an updated gitlink.

  The clone you work in, when you *do* have to make a new submodule commit, can be far away from the superproject-and-its-submodule, or you can just use the clone you already have there.  Just remember that the superproject Git will, at some point, reach down into the submodule Git and do a detached-HEAD checkout.  (If you are doing work *in* the submodule at that time, that could mess your work up, so make sure that this doesn't happen—i.e., don't let anyone run any Git commands *in* the superproject—or use a different clone, or an added work-tree, or something.  It doesn't matter *how* you make sure the superproject Git doesn't mess you up, just that you *do* make sure.)
- A *subtree*, however, is designed to be, or have, a repeatable "extract this new Git repository from the larger, encompassing, outer Git repository" process.

Making this process repeatable is a little bit tricky, but *is* possible, provided certain constraints are met.  In particular, we know that the commit hash ID of *any given commit* is *absolutely 100% controlled* by the complete contents of that commit, including the commit hash IDs in the history leading up to that commit.  As long as the contents of the commit do not change, any *future* computation of the hash ID will exactly match the *past* computation of the hash ID of the same content.

What this means is that if the larger repository (the "supertree"? we need a name for this: let's just call it **R**) only has *new commits added*, and we apply a consisting *filtering function* to each of the *existing* commits, the filtering of some previous copy of **R** will have produced some new subtree output **S<sub>0</sub>**.  Repeating that same process on **R** now, with new commits added, will produce a superset **S<sub>1</sub>**.  This superset will contain all the same commits that **S<sub>0</sub>** had, plus any new commits that are the result of filtering the new **R** commits.  Since those only *added on* to commits in **R**, the new **S** commits only *add on* to **S** as well.

To make this work, *no commit in **R** can ever be rebased or otherwise discarded.*  Doing so disrupts our nice superset property for **S**.

But: can we add *new* commits to some extracted **S<sub>i</sub>**, then import those commits back to **R**?  The answer is a conditional yes.  We must know, or find out, which commits are actually new in this **S**, and we must then make sure that if and when we do add them to **R**, we do so in a way that, when filtered, anything we put into them *during* this process "filters away".  This can be tricky: we must preserve all the metadata except for the `tree` object.

If it's necessary to change out this metadata for any reason, our remaining alternative is to consider this particular **S<sub>i</sub>** its own red-headed stepchild, as it were.  We import the new commits, then declare **S<sub>i</sub>** to be *persona non grata* and generate a replacement **S<sub>i+1</sub>** and throw away all use of **S<sub>i</sub>**.

In practice, these rules *can* work, and `git subtree split` and `git subtree merge` can handle the filtering (creation of some **S**) and back-import of updates.  But these little traps, where something can go wrong, do exist, and `git subtree` doesn't get a lot of attention on the Git mailing list.  The submodule stuff is much more maintained.  It's often more annoying, and has its own sharp edges, but it's definitely better-supported.